# How can I fetch the IP address of a website in xamarin forms application?

Tags: xamarin.android, ip-address

My code is below. The code perfectly returns the IP address of any website address in C# in Asp.net core.

But does not do anything in Xamarin android application at all. I have tried a lot but got frustrated.

```
string url = "https://www.google.com/";
Uri myUri = new Uri(url);
var addresses = await Dns.GetHostAddressesAsync(myUri.Host);

return addresses?[0] + " from Android application";
```

It does not return any value and does not show any error. How could I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to to like below:

```
string url = "https://www.google.com/";
Uri myUri = new Uri(url);
var addresses = Dns.GetHostByName(myUri.Host);
string ip = addresses.AddressList[0].ToString();
```

Comment: Yes, I tried but that's also failed and the app stuck at this Dns.GetHostByName() point.

Answer (score 0):

Well, finally I could get a solution for this.

```
string ipAddresse = Dns.GetHostAddressesAsync(myUri.Host).ConfigureAwait(false).GetAwaiter().GetResult()[0].ToString();
```

Just need to remove await activity as the following process. It works as expected.